# Django complex distinct based on timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

community, need a bit of help:

Having hard time with implementing business rules in my query:

I have a model Entity with field 'timestamp'
for example I have 10 instances of Entity for 24 hours. I need to distinct() or exclude() Entities if they have timestamp in range of 30 minutes between them. So if I have 8 instances with interval of 1 hour and 2 instances with interval of 30 minutes, I need to output count of 9 instances. Hope it's a clear explanation of what I'm looking for. Please refer any helpful documentation or article on complex querying. Thanks!

litterally have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Right now everything I can to try is to:

y.objects.filter(timestamp__date='2025-03-13').order_by('timestamp').values_list('timestamp__time')
and compare it one by one in a loop

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.